# Can I add additional services to container later in the app component?

Tags: lazy-loading, blazor-webassembly, razor-class-library

I use lazy loading to load two RCLs in the `App` component, Since I don't know which assembly is loaded until App runs I want to add additional services to the `builder.Services` container later in the app component is it possible?